# Building Gmail add-ons with Angular framework?

Tags: gmail, angular8, google-workspace-add-ons

We are finishing up an [Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2) which was written using Angular 8 with typescript. I am doing my investigation into what it will take to write a gmail add-on. I've gone through the [quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/quickstart) using Apps Script. I've also looked at the [clasp tool](https://github.com/google/clasp).

Is it possible to create a Google add-on with the angular framework?
Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. Gmail add-ons are distinct from "Editor Add-ons"(ie. add-ons built for Google Sheets, Google Docs or Google Forms) and are developed strictly with App Script using a widget-based model. Furthermore, Gmail Add-on development **does not** grant developer's direct access to the DOM. [See restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/gmail-restrictions#gmail_add-ons)

Comment: That is what i suspected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to build Gmail add-ons with Angular framework.

Gmail add-ons are distinct from "Editor Add-ons"(ie. add-ons built for Google Sheets, Google Docs or Google Forms) and are developed strictly with App Script using a widget-based model.

Furthermore, Gmail Add-on development does not grant developer's direct access to the DOM. 
[See restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/gmail-restrictions#gmail_add-ons) of Gmail addons.

Answer (score 1):

The short and simple answer is no.

Google Workspace Add-ons UI are created using the [Cards framework](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/cards). Besides Google Apps Script, nowadays it's possible to use programming languages like Java hosted in Google Cloud Run or other hosting infrastructures as long as they deliver JSON to build the add-on UI using the Cards framework.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/).

Typically you end up having to manipluate the DOM.  This tool caters for most the key functions in an easy to use library.

Not so sure how you will use Angular but it is possible to build rich experiences based on this library.